# manage with URL duplication in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, duplicates

I have a real estate website, coded in Symfony 2.

Every morning, we automatically import properties from a real estate software, and we update the data base.

The URL is rewritten with the title of the property and the ID, like :

```
.../%title%-%ID%
```

Sometimes, the real estate agent change the title of the property, so the URL changes as well.

It's creating a duplicate content in Google, because 2 URL now exists for the same page.

I want to fix it, to automatically add a redirect 301 from the old URL to the new one.

How can I do that in Symfony 2?

Thanks for your help !

Mathieu

Comment: Do you have problem to detect that an URL is *old* or to send the 301 response?

Comment: yes, my problem is to detect that the URL has changed.

Comment: Is the ID a constant? Can't you use it in order to detect changes in the name? Can you please add the code of the routing, the code which update the title and the scheme of the database?

Comment: Yep, the property has an unic ID. Here an example :
First URL is : .../vente-ferme-bressane-entierement-renovee-aproximite-de-belleville-CH+28416
And when the agent change the title of the property : .../vente-ferme-bressane-entierement-renovee-4-km-de-chatillon-sur-chalaronne-CH+28416
(sorry it's in french, but you can see the ID at the end of the URL)

Comment: any suggestion ? thanks

Comment: Yes: compare the old and the new URL, detect the old URL and redirect to the new one. We can't help you precisely if you don't show your code or explain what have you tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll ask to my developer.

Comment: How do you use the ID? *because 2 URL now exists for the same page* You should store each advertisement only once. You can use a [OneToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) association in order to keep the different URLs of the same advertisement. Then you can use a redirection when an *old* URL is detected.

Comment: How do you know which URL is the new one and which is the old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for all your comments.
I'm working with Mat Bios and you help us to find the solution.

We find a way to detect old url and then to make a redirect 301 in the controller.

`return $this->redirect($currentUrl, 301);`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a generic Url. The generic Url would be the one Google would know about. Any Url with the title would be routed to the generic Url.

Create a rule that catches all urls with the pattern `//myApp/%title%-%ID%` and causes a redirect `//myapp/property/%ID%`

You can do all this in your routing.yml

```
GenericRoute:   pattern: /myapp/properties/{propertyId}   
    defaults:
      _controller: Bundle:Controller:action

TitleRoute:   
    pattern: /myapp/{title}/{propertyId}   
    defaults:
      _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
      route: GenericRoute
      permanent: true
```

Comment: thanks for your help Brig :) We need to keep the property title in the url, the belga's solution works.